# Best way to execute a method after some time in Spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

The user sends a request for a product. If no seller has responded within 9 hours, the system should send this request to other sellers with a similar product.

The Scheduler isn't an option for me, because it should be exactly 9 hours for each request the users send.

So what would be a proper way to do that?

P.S The requests, users, etc are stored in a Postgres database.

Comment: What precision for "exactly 9 hours" do you nee, which the Scheduler can't offer?

Comment: @JensSchauder
Well, I guess you could set the scheduler to wake up every minute, but that would be a waste of resources if there are only a few offers to be checked much later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a heavy framework, but my go to solution for any complex scheduling is Quartz http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/quick-start.html

Job data can be persisted to db, has built in heartbeats, locking, clustering, missfire handling, canceling... a mature scheduling framework.

A simple trigger should be enough for your use case, from their examples:

```
    // get a "nice round" time a few seconds in the future...
    Date startTime = DateBuilder.nextGivenSecondDate(null, 15);

    // job1 will only fire once at date/time "ts"
    JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

    SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1").startAt(startTime).build();

    // schedule it to run!
    Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

The hard part is to do the initial setup of quartz in your project and it's worth it if you expect to have other scenarios where you want something to trigger reliably some time in the future (with or without recurrence).